# R - How to dynamically construct a function name in mutate with quasiquotation

Tags: r, dplyr

Firstly it is my first question on StackOverflow, I hope I will write it the good way. If not, don't hesitate to tell me... And sorry for my approximative english!

I would like to use the mutate function from dplyr to change the type of the columns of a data.frame, but without knowing in advance the new type. Thus I would like to create dynamically the function name (for example "as.numeric", "as.factor"), taking the new type from another data.frame.

Here is a concrete example (what I want to do is for data.frames with more than 100 variables, so you will understand I don't want to do this manually!):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Name = c("Roger", "Steve"), Age = c("40", "32"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
glimpse(df)

Observations: 2
Variables: 2
$ Name <chr> "Roger", "Steve"
$ Age  <chr> "40", "32"

types <- data.frame(Field = c("Name", "Age"), OldType = c("character", "character"), NewType = c("factor", "integer"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
glimpse(types)

Observations: 2
Variables: 3
$ Field   <chr> "Name", "Age"
$ OldType <chr> "character", "character"
$ NewType <chr> "factor", "integer"
```

I searched during a long time and found a lot of documentation on quasiquotation, and I tried a few things, but without never getting the expected result. Here are two attempts I made:

```
# First attempt
for(i in 1:nrow(types)){
  field <- types$Field[i]
  field_quo <- enquo(field)
  new_type <- paste0("as.", types$NewType[i], "(", field, ")")
  new_type_quo <- enquo(new_type)
  df <- df %>% mutate(!!field_quo := !!new_type_quo)
}
glimpse(df)

Observations: 2
Variables: 2
$ Name <chr> "as.factor(Name)", "as.factor(Name)"
$ Age  <chr> "as.integer(Age)", "as.integer(Age)"
```

=> the function calls are considered as strings, and the value of the columns are replaced instead of their types.

```
# Second attempt
for(i in 1:nrow(types)){
  field <- types$Field[i]
  field_quo <- ensym(field)
  new_type <- paste0("as.", types$NewType[i], "(", field, ")")
  new_type_quo <- ensym(new_type)
  df <- df %>% mutate(!!field_quo := !!new_type_quo)
}
```

Here I get an error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: as.factor(Name).
```

I guess the mutate function considers what is in parenthesis as a whole variable name?

I have tried other things but without success. I must admit that I am not a R expert and I have difficulties to fully understand this concept of quasiquotation, despite the quality of the documentation. So I know that I am doing the things wrong, but Idon't know why nor how to do it right... Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: library(dplyr) , parse_guess will help you , df %mutate_all(parse_guess). It automatically detects the structure of the data frame.

Comment: Thank you Hunaidkhan, I didn't know this function. I tried it and in some cases it could fit my needs, but not in this one. For example, here, the "Name" field type is let to "character" where I would like to have "factor". And I may want to coerce some character fields into integer: my datas are sometimes not clean and there can be errors - for example a string where I expect an integer -  that could make the "parse_guess" function think the variable is string, whereas I want integer - coerce in integer will transofrm the "wrong" strings into NA, and that suits me. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interesting question. I think I found a solution using map2 from purrr package in tidyverse.

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(Name = c("Roger", "Steve"), Age = c("40", "32"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
types <- data.frame(Field = c("Name", "Age"), OldType = c("character", "character"), NewType = c("factor", "integer"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)

# Create a column with function names that is needed. I.e. adding as.
types <- types %>% 
  mutate(newType2 = paste0("as.", NewType))

# Then loop over column names and functions
df2 <- map2_dfc(types$Field, 
         types$newType2, 
         ~df %>% 
           select_(.x) %>% 
           mutate_all(.y)
  ) %>% as_tibble()
```

gives you

```
> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Name    Age
  <fct> <int>
1 Roger    40
2 Steve    32
```

But for easy data type conversion try. which gives you a suitable data type for each column. However, it never suggests factors. But then you can use convert if you want.

```
library(hablar)

df %>% 
    retype() %>%
    convert(fct(Name))
```

Comment: Thanks davsjob, that's perfect! And more rapid as a for loop (I have tested your solution against a for loop (using taiki-sakai's solution) with a large dataset, it was the fastet).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `get`. This allows you to retrieve an object by passing in its name as a character, so `get('as.factor')` will return the `as.factor` function. Fitting this into your previous attempts:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(types)) {
    field <- sym(types$Field[i])
    typeFun <- get(paste0('as.', types$NewType[i]))
    df <- df %>% 
        mutate(!!field := typeFun(!!field))
}
glimpse(df)

Observations: 2
Variables: 2
$ Name <fct> Roger, Steve
$ Age  <int> 40, 32
```

Comment: Thanks @taiki-sakai, function "get" was exactly what I was looking for in the context of using a for loop! This works great. I won't accept your answer as the best solution because davsjob's solution below seems better to me (and more rapid after some tests), but I will keep yours in mind for the future!